# probability (waiting time = infinity) for a poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am new here so if I violate any rule, please inform.

Consider the stochastic process given by $\{ N(t) : t \geq 0 \}$ which is time homogeneous poisson process with arrival rate $\lambda$. Let $W_n$ be the waiting time, i.e, $W_n = \inf \{t\geq0:N(t)=n \}$.

We want to show that $P(W_k < \infty) = 1 \ \ \forall k=1,2,\ldots $.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What would the probability be at infinity?

Comment: The result is quite general: each interarrival time is almost surely finite hence the sum $W_k$ of the $k$ first interarrival times is almost surely finite.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly we may assume that $N(t)$ is right-continuous with monotone increasing sample path.

Then $t \geq W_n$ if and only if $N(t) \geq n$ and we have

$$\Bbb{P}(W_n \leq t) = \Bbb{P}(N(t) \geq n) = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^{k}}{k!} e^{-\lambda t} = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^{k}}{k!} e^{-\lambda t}. $$

Now taking $t \to \infty$, the monotone convergence theorem yields the desired result $\Bbb{P}(W_n < \infty) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Inter event times for a poisson process are exponentially distributed with pdf

$$X \sim \lambda t e^{-\lambda t}$$

([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process))

The probability that the interevent waiting time is less than or equal $t \in [0, \infty)$ is given by:-

$$\mathbb{P}(t=T) = \int_0^\infty \lambda s e^{-\lambda s} dt\\
\to 1 ~\text{as}~ t \to \infty.$$

So the probability of (at least) one event, becomes 1 as $t$ tends to infinity. Hence, the probability of no events (= 1 - $\mathbb{P}(\text{at least}~ 1 ~\text{event})$) tends to $0$ as $t \to \infty$

Comment: Why does $P(T=\infty)$ equal that limit? In my opinion, your answer needs some explanation.

Comment: Hmmm, have attempted to edit, but I think I'm hitting against mthe limits of my own knowledge. If you have a better idea of how to edit, then please feel free.

Comment: Something is not right: $N(t+\tau)-N(t)\sim \mathrm{po}(\lambda \tau)$ and also $k$ does not appear in your first formula.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Unfortunately I am at work right now and I'm not able to keep editing! I will try to fix at lunchtime.

Comment: I've had a go at simplifying (a lot) and re-writing. I think it is a simpler and better answer now.

Comment: I have missed the part where we generalise to the case where $k >1$, but did's comment adresses this. I hope this answer is more helpful now anyway.